# Embedding javascript on all blog platforms (creating a javascript badge)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We would like to create a widget that basically acts as a badge for users to copy and paste on their blog. The way we're doing it is as follows -

We require the user to paste code similar to as follows into the HTML side of their blog post -

```
<script src="http://[our-remote-js]?blogg_id=XXXXXX">
<div id="div-name">
```

In our remote javascript file, we are querying our database for (`blogg_id=XXXXXX`) via ajax, constructing HTML at run time, and then setting the innerHTML for `"div-name"` to the HTML for the badge.

What we're running into is on Blogger, some templates will strip out the JavaScript and just leave the `<div>` tag. 
On wordpress.org sites, the javascript is stripped out completely.

Is there a cleaner solution to this? One way I was thinking was, kinda as is done in PHP, where you can pass a querystring parameter to an image (`blogg_id=XXXXXX`), can you do that in .NET?

Any thoughts? Examples?

Comment: You can generate image in your .NET code, and make users display a badge like `<img src="http://yourserver.com/generate_badge_image.aspx?blogg_id=XXXXXX" />`

Comment: Another possibility is IFRAME pointing to your page. Since it will be your page, you can execute any code you want, including JavaScript